# How do I have to tell Java where to find native libraries?

Tags: java, dll, path

I am trying to figure out if my Java is misbehaving or not.

I have cleaned and built my Java project in NetBeans and then tried to run the program on the command line with the following command:

```
java -jar ProjectName.jar
```

I get the following error:

> The library x.dll could not be loaded by Windows.   Make sure that the
>   library is in your Path environment variable.   Exception in thread
>   "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError.

Does this mean that for every project with library files in the dist folder, I need to include it in the path environment variable?  This sounds awfully troublesome and I would have thought that Java would be smart enough to look inside the lib folder for these library files.  Or do I need to configure something else in the IDE to do this?

Comment: *"I would have thought that java would be smart enough to look inside the lib folder for these library files."*  What 'lib' folder?  I think you will find the lib directory is an artifact of your IDE and the way it arranges things.

Comment: Ah, you are right.  I am using NetBeans.  Let me rephrase/edit my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
java -Djava.library.path=<path where dll located> -jar ProjectName.jar
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to include the dll or jar in the classpath when you launch the application / Java.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Comment: It is better to provide a link to the most up to date JavaDocs.  I will edit your answer in a moment to include that.  BTW - would the down-voter care to share their reasoning?  IMWTK.

Comment: I believe the down vote was due to answering for jars not dlls. Point taken.

Comment: Not sure what the down vote was for.  I tried this out and something is still messed up: The command "java -cp /path/to/lib -jar ProjectName.jar" still gives me the same error. Hmm.. any ideas?

Comment: The class path and the library path are different animals completely.